# Will chrome devtools network still show status 200 even if cloudflare blocks the request, or will it give 403?

Tags: cloudflare

I'm sending the same fetch GET request to the server over and over and it is returning with status code 200 on all of the fethces. Is it being blocked by the Cloudflare server and just being displayed as a 200 or is it actually passing Cloudflare?